# Slow process in code

Tags: awk

can you help to improve this code to be faster .. with 50000 lines in my file this take a lot time.

I appreciate your help

input

```
17/11/27 03:13:50:480000
17/11/27 03:12:54:380000
17/11/27 03:14:39:980000
```

output

```
1195787648480000
1195787592380000
1195787697980000
```

my code

```
ts=$(date -d'01/06/1980 00:00:00' +%s)

lap=18

cat file |
    while read tt 
    do 
    dt=`echo $tt | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F"/" '{print $2"/"$3"/"$1}'`
    tm=`echo $tt | awk '{print substr($2,1,8)}'`
    ms=`echo $tt | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F":" '{print $NF}'`
    line=`echo $dt" " $tm`
    echo $line\ $(date -d "${line/// }" "+%s") | 
    awk '{print (($3 - '$ts') + '$lap')'$ms'}' 
    done
```

Please, help me to improve my code to get results faster.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with appropriate tags, such as the language you are using

Comment: Use less `awk` calls. Another option would be [MPI-IO](http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/I590/node86.html), which is specifically designed to handle big big files.

Comment: Any time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

similar with `gawk`

```
$ awk -F'[/: ]' -v ts=$(date -d'01/06/1980' +%s)  \
                -v lap=18 '{ms=$NF; $NF=""; d=sprintf(20$0); 
                            print mktime(d)+lap-ts ms}' file

1195787648480000
1195787592380000
1195787697980000
```

Answer (score 3):

With single GNU **`awk`** process:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*|/|:' -v ts=$(date -d'01/06/1980 00:00:00' +%s) -v lap=18 '{ 
     print (mktime(sprintf("20%d %d %d %d %d %d",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)) - ts)+lap $NF 
}' file
```

The output:

```
1195791248480000
1195791192380000
1195791297980000
```

---

Enjoy )